# Taking x number of last columns from a file in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a txt file with columns such as name, position, department, etc. I need to get certain characters from each column to generate a username and password for each listing.

I'm approaching this problem by first separating the columns with:

```
awk 'NR>10{print $1, $2, $3, ...etc}' $filename
#This skips the header information and simply prints out each specified column.
```

And then moving on to grab each character that I need from their respective fields.

The problem now is that each row is not uniform. For example the listings are organized as such:

`(lastName, firstName, middleInitial, position, departmentName)`

Some of the entries in the text file do not have certain fields such as middle initial. So when I try to list fields 3, 4, and 5 the entries without their middle initials return:

```
(position, departmentName, empty/null (I'm not sure how awk handles this))
```

The good news is that I do not need the middle initial, so I can ignore these listings . How can I go about grabbing the last 2 (in this example) columns from the file so I can isolate the fields that *every* entry has in order to cut the necessary characters out of them?

Comment: Can you add some sample data to test with, the expected results, and the results you're getting with the code you've written so far (even if it's an error)?  Oh, and the code itself, in as close to a runnable state as you can make it. Have a look at the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) description for tips. Good luck!

Comment: Wow I really need some formatting help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them by `$(NF-1)` and `$NF`, they are last 2nd column and last column

```
echo "1,2,3,4" | awk -F,  'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

`NF` means number of fields. If you have 4 fields. (NF-1) would be column 3, and `$(NF-1)` is the value of column 3.

Output would be
`3,4`

Another example with different length fields in file:
sample.csv

```
1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d
```

Run

```
awk -F,  'BEGIN{OFS=","}{print $(NF-1), $NF}' sample.csv
```

Output:

```
4,5
c,d
```

Comment: Does this take the last field from each row independently?
So if one row has 4 total fields and another has 5 total fields, $NF would take the 4th for the first row and the 5th for the second?

Comment: @LukeDangerKozorosky Yes, it is. See my second example in the answer

Comment: This is great! Now, since I am reading in a file instead of echoing the literal values, would it be more beneficial to use a head command to get rid of the junk at the top instead of trying to pipe certain fields into this command?

Example: instead of using awk 'NR>10{print $1, $2, $3, ...etc}' $filename
and giving the specific columns, use head to skip the first 10 lines and read the rest of the data?

Comment: @LukeDangerKozorosky In my 2nd example, the command processes file

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @LukeDangerKozorosky default field delimiter is space. or `awk -F" " '{execution}'  inputfile`